# Change a image depending on a generated nr in a input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following working code: http://jsfiddle.net/NtHwN/4/

It will deduct the number that is in the input field when pressing the hyperlink or button by -1 and will do this just one time for both. This works great.

Now I have 3 images: 1.jpg, 2.jpg and 3.jpg. I want to show this image depending on the number in the input field. So I've added:

`<div id="img_select"><img src="test/images/3.jpg" alt=""></div>`

Now, if the user clicks the button or hyperlink, the nr will change from 3 to 2. When this happens, the image should also change from "test/images/3.jpg" to "test/images/2.jpg", but how to do this with jQuery? (so the nr in the input field corresponds with the nr in the .jpg)

Played around with this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#image_select').attr('img_', {
        'child': 'img',
        'change': 'src',
        'formatValue': function (value) { 
            return 'test/images/' + value + '.jpg'
        }
    });
});
```

But with no luck.

Kind regards,

Maurice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".minus").one("click", function(){
        var value = parseInt($("#sum").val());
        value = value - 1;
        $("#sum").val(value);
        $("#img_select > img").attr("src","test/images/" + value + ".jpg")
    });
});
```

That should just concatenate your field value into the image string and insert it into the `src` attribut` of your image.  You'll probably also need to add some code to prevent your value going below 1.

Comment: Thanks all, went for this code since it changes the image div only

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NtHwN/6/

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".minus").one("click", function(){
        var value = parseInt($("#sum").val()) - 1;
        $("#sum").val(value);
        $("img").attr("src", "test/images/" + value + ".jpg");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input size=10 id="sum" value="3">
<input class="minus" type=button value="-">
<a class="minus" href="#">minus</a>
<div id="img_select"><img src="test/images/3.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler:

jQuery("#img_select img").attr("src", "test/images/" + jQuery("#sum").val() + ".jpg");

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/NtHwN/7/